# Train Multi-Input Keras NN with batch of training data

Tags: keras

I would like to use Keras to train a multi-input NN with a batch of training data, but I'm not able to pass a set of input and output samples to execute a *fit* or a *train_on_batch* on the model.

My NN is defined as following:

```
    i1 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,))
    i2 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,))
    i3 = keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,))
    i_layer = keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')
    embedded_i1 = i_layer(i1)
    embedded_i2 = i_layer(i2)
    embedded_i3 = i_layer(i3)

    middle_concatenation = keras.layers.concatenate([embedded_i1, embedded_i2, embedded_i3], axis=1)

    out = keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(middle_concatenation)

    model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[i1, i2, i3], outputs=out)
    model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

For example, an instance of the input (successfully used for predict the output) is the following:

`[array([[0.1, 0.2]]), array([[0.3, 0.5]]), array([[0.1, 0.3]])]`

But when I try to train my model with:

```
    inputs = [[np.array([[0.1, 0.2]]), np.array([[0.3, 0.5]]), np.array([[0.1, 0.3]])],
                     [np.array([[0.2, 0.1]]), np.array([[0.5, 0.3]]), np.array([[0.3, 0.1]])]
                         ]
    outputs = np.ones(len(inputs))
    model.fit(inputs, outputs)
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking model input: you are passing a list as input to your model, but the model expects a list of 3 Numpy arrays instead. The list you passed was: [[array([[ 0.1,  0.2]]), array([[ 0.3,  0.5]]), array([[ 0.1,  0.3]])], [array([[ 0.2,  0.1]]), array([[ 0.5,  0.3]]), array([[ 0.3,  0.1]])]]
```

What am I doing wrong?
How can I train a multi-input NN with a batch of input/output samples?

Thank you!

Comment: I think you may want to look into [merge](https://keras.io/layers/merge/) layer and have three separate branches condense down to a combined network, otherwise there wouldn't be much difference with combining you input into one

Comment: @djk47463 Thanks for your hint! I need the three inputs to share their weights. So I build the layer 'i_layer', added every input to this layer and then concatenate the three outputs of this layer to build the rest of the NN.
NB: I just deleted some internal layers in order to simplify the code.

Anyway, do you know how to solve the train problem?

Comment: sorry I grazed the code to fast, didn't realize you were already doing that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is just incorrect formatting. You can't pass a list to keras, only numpy arrays, so when you have your data structured like

```
 inputs = [[np.array([[0.1, 0.2]]), np.array([[0.3, 0.5]]), np.array([[0.1, 0.3]])],
                     [np.array([[0.2, 0.1]]), np.array([[0.5, 0.3]]), np.array([[0.3, 0.1]])]
                         ]
```

You need to pass one list element into your model at a time. You will also need to pass one output value to the model at a time. To do this, structure you `outputs` like this

```
outputs = [np.ones(1) for x in inputs]

[array([ 1.]), array([ 1.])]
```

Then you can loop over the the fit function like this

```
 for z in range(0,len(inputs)):
     model.fit(inputs[z],outputs[z],batch_size=1)
```

you can also replace `model.fit` with `model.train_on_batch()` instead, see [docs](https://keras.io/models/sequential/)

however to avoid the loop, you could just have 3 numpy arrays stored in your `inputs` list and have you single `outputs` as a numpy array. If you only want to train on a single batch at a time, you could set your batch size to do that.

```
inputs = [np.array([[0.1, 0.2],[0.2, 0.1]]), np.array([[0.3, 0.5],[0.5, 0.3]]), np.array([[0.1, 0.3],[0.3, 0.1]])]

outputs = np.ones(inputs[0].shape[0])

model.fit(inputs,outputs,batch_size=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that right now you are using a list of lists as input, although keras expects a list of arrays.

You need to convert your list so that it looks like `[array_inputs_1, array_inputs_2, array_inputs_3]`, where each input array is the array of inputs you would pass the model if it had only that input layer, you just put the 3 of them inside a list.

Using your data the correct input should be:

```
[np.array([[0.1, 0.2], [0.2, 0.1]]), 
 np.array([[0.3, 0.5], [0.5, 0.3]]), 
 np.array([[0.1, 0.3], [0.1, 0.3]])]
```

This way, as long as all 3 input arrays have the same number of elements, keras will know how to divide tham into batches.

Comment: Thank you @gionni.
You are completely right. Now it works!